# Servidor GoDaddy bloquea correos salientes

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, godaddy

Tengo un problema con mi servidor de GoDaddy. Hace poco hice una publicación del envío de correos a través de php con **PHPMailer**. De forma local funciona perfecto, el problema es al subirlo y probarlo.

En **producción me genera un error 500** alusivo a que hay un error con el servidor o algo asi, ya le cambié a la configuración del MX pero aun asi no funciona, los correos aún no se envían y me sigue generando un error 500.

¿Alguien que le haya pasado lo mismo?

Adjunto el codigo que utilizo

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication

    $mail->Username   = 'correo@domio.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'passwordCorreo';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom(correo@domio.com, $username);
    $mail->addAddress($address, 'Contacto');     // Add a recipient

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = "<b>".$body."</b>";

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: a mi me paso algo similar, lo que hice fue que reinicie los valores del correo, así como también solicitar ayuda con los valores (Ayuda técnica) y funciono. Inténtalo a mi me funciono. Saludos!!!

Comment: Hola Angel, puedes pasar la configuracion de phpmailer? recuerdo que te la pase yo no?

Comment: la configuracion quedo tal cual el post anterior. aqui no puedo comentar el codigo pero editare este post para mi configuracion del phpmailer

Comment: vale, cuando lo edites y pongas miro a ver si te puedo echar una mano

Comment: como he comentado, de forma local funciona sin problemas, creo q todo es en el go daddy pero ya conigure el MX y aun asi no funciona.

Comment: Cambia esta configuración y me cuentas
SMTP_PORT: 465
SMTP_Secure: 'ssl'

Comment: creo que te falla por el puerto smtp y por la autenticacion cambiala como te indico abajo y me cuentas

Comment: Pon el error tal cual sale, pues "o algo así" no es útil para ayudarte.

Comment: el erro que me sale es un codigo 500, no hay mas informacion.